# Doctrine 2 paginator with exotic join throws error

Tags: php, join, doctrine-orm, pagination

I've run into an issue with the doctrine 2 paginator. I made a very basic example which will explain the situation:

```
$queryBuilder->select('entity');
$queryBuilder->join('SomeModule\Entity\SomeEntity', 's', 'WITH', '(s.objectClass = :class AND p.foreignKey = :foreignkey');
$paginator = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($queryBuilder);
```

causes the error 'Cannot count query which selects two FROM components, cannot make distinction' in:
Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\WhereInWalker

It does that because there are two components, but in this case, no columns are selected from the 'SomeModule\Entity\SomeEntity':

```
if (count($rootComponents) > 1) {
    throw new \RuntimeException("Cannot count query which selects two FROM components, cannot make distinction");
}
```

In my case, it works when I comment the exception, because it will just use the first $rootComponent. Does anyone know a solution for this exotic join, without changing/extending the WhereInWalker class?

I used version 2.4.6 of the ORM, when I use the master branch:
https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Pagination/WhereInWalker.php
The issue is resolved. But I'd rather not use the master branch in our environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no solution for using exotic joins, without changing/extending the WhereInWalker class. 
The fix is now in Doctrine 2.5.0-alpha2 which is released now so you could upgrade to that if you'd like. 2.5 is scheduled to be released next month so you could wait until then if you'd like.

If you want to keep your existing Doctrine install as is changing the WhereInWalker and related classes is not terribly difficult.
First you'll need to copy 
`Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\LimitSubqueryWalker` `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\WhereInWalker` and `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\CountWalker`

From Doctrine master branch to your own code base and change the namespace accordingly. So you might use `AcmeBundle\Components\Pagination\WhereInWalker` or something similar.

You'll need to create your own Paginator which extends `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator` and then copy past the functions `count` and `getIterator` from the parent class. Then update the functions to use your own Walkers you created above. So in count() You replace:

`$this->appendTreeWalker($countQuery, 'Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\CountWalker');`

with

`$this->appendTreeWalker($countQuery, 'AcmeBundle\Components\Pagination\CountWalker');`

Do the same for WhereInWalker and LimitSubqueryWalker in the getIterator method.
Then everything will work fine. I just did something similar with the KnpPaginator to resolve this same issue. It does create a bit of maintenance headache so be sure to undo these things if you ever update to 2.5.

Comment: We fixed it by branching the 2.4 version and applying some changes to WhereInWalker